# Is there any other way to close a frameless window in electron 5.0.1

Tags: electron

i have a inner window, which is frameless and i created a button to close the window. After adding the event listener, it doesn't close..it does not return any error

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const remote = electron.remote

const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn')

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
})
```

Comment: I think that you have to create an event in the main process, not in the renderer window process to close the window. docs for reference https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindow

Comment: Thank you, but i have created an event in the main process and it isn't working still

Comment: have you verified that your event handler is being triggered?

Answer (score 2):

Send the ipc event to the main process using ipcRenderer.send() function

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const remote = electron.remote
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn')

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       ipcRenderer.send('close-window');
})
```

in main process, catch the close event and close the required window

```
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
ipcMain.on('close-window',()=>{

    //if mainWindow is the window object
    mainWindow.close();

})
```